# DefaultValues from useForm is not updated correctly with useFormContext

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

see example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-franklin-d4o5z

The Default Value set in useForm itself works fine. however, when this used with useFormContext, it is not functional correctly; as it only take the first init. value.

on the example, when the dialog pop up, the target value changed to "test", i am expecting the value got filled by "test" too. however, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `defaultValue` via `useForm` will only set the form values on the initial render. It behaves similar to `useState`, which will also only use the passed argument on the first render.

So you have two options here:

- Conditionally render your dialog only when `detailOpen` is set to
  `true`

[image: Edit example using conditional render]

- use `reset` from RHF

[image: Edit example using reset]

You also had a small typo in your `<Details />` component. You set `<Controller />` name property to "number" instead to "name".